# Relation or Pointer?

Tags: parse-platform

If I have a class titled `Article`, and I want to add an `Author` column (which is class type `User`), should I use relation or pointer? There can only be one `Author`, but that `Author` can write many articles. I'm assuming pointer, but just making sure.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you assume that an article will have 1 or 0 authors, then use a pointer. If there may be more than one author, use an Array.

When you have a one-many relation, you have a choice of using arrays or PFRelations. Arrays are a lot easier to deal with if the max number of entries is not large, let's say 100 or less. Perhaps the most important advantage is that you can use includeKey when querying to bring in all the related objects with one query.

If the number of related objects is large, you have to use PFRelation.

Comment: You are welcome. The array/PFRelation stuff is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is to use a pointer for one-to-one or one-to-many relationship. Use a relation when you have a many-to-many relationship. I would say in your case it sounds like you want to use a pointer type. This [guide](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide) is useful.